# Rewriting URL still redirects to old URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to access

```
https://www.onlybrighton.com/optin-ninja/onlybrightona/
```

using

```
https://www.onlybrighton.com/jani
```

but it doesn't seem to be working right and it's redirecting me to

```
/onlybrightona/
```

URL when I enter

```
/jani
```

URL in browser

I am using follwing rule:

```
RewriteRule ^jani$ /optin-ninja/onlybrightona/ [QSA,L]
```

Apologies for being so blunt but I really am new into this.

Edit: in a nutshell my problem is *.htaccess rule redirecting, but not rewriting*

Comment: I have been following this tutorial:  https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: Nope only wordpress default rules:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lp-variation-id
RewriteRule ^go/([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/ /go/$1?lp-variation-id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lp-variation-id
RewriteRule ^go/([^/]*)? /wp-content/plugins/landing-pages/modules/module.redirect-ab-testing.php?permalink_name=$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^landing-page=([^/]*)? /wp-content/plugins/landing-pages/modules/module.redirect-ab-testing.php?permalink_name=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try it :

```
RewriteRule    ^jani/?$    https://www.onlybrighton.com/optin-ninja/onlybrightona/    [R=301,NC,L]
```

Please try above code and let me know.

Comment: Thanks foe your answer but it is still same. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: @user3019203 I have one question did you mean when you write this url https://www.onlybrighton.com/jani in your browser and you want to open this link https://www.onlybrighton.com/optin-ninja/onlybrightona/ right ?

Comment: Yes right but i need to have the URL of onlybrighton.com/jani

Comment: @user3019203 if yes then its working fine for me. so i think issue is on your browser cache please clear cache or try it on different browser.

Comment: Are you seeing onlybrighton.com/jani as URL with contents of /optin-ninja/onlybrightona?

Comment: @user3019203 Yes when i write this url onlybrighton.com/jani then redirect it to /optin-ninja/onlybrightona

Comment: I don't want redirection, i rather want URL rewriting here :)

Comment: @user3019203  Sorry, But not getting you.

Comment: I think what mean was he wants is, when the URL should load the content of /optin-ninja/onlybrightona on the onlybrighton.com/jani without /optin-ninja/onlybrightona written on address bar.
P.S he doesn't want to do a 301 redirect. @jalpa